# Вопрос оборотень - показывает одно, а в "истории правок" - другое

Tags: дефект, миграция

Вот такой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/360962) встретил:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А теперь смотрите, идем в историю правок, и видим чудное:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Явно дефект ruSO.

Comment: [Вот](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1375979/questions-with-different-titles-than-their-revision-history-suggests) 45 таких вопросов.

Comment: Есть ощущение, что откат к пошлой версии просто отсутствует в списке ревизий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по [подобным правкам](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/222284/revisions), откат к старой версии не фиксировался на Хэшкоде или просто не участвовал в миграции. Впрочем, то, что вопрос из вопроса был откачен назад, кажется довольно странным.

PS: Спасибо [@Glorfindel](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/223536/glorfindel) за [список таких вопросов](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1375979/questions-with-different-titles-than-their-revision-history-suggests).

Comment: Таки да, веб-архив подтверждает сию гипотезу http://web.archive.org/web/20141003144523/http://hashcode.ru:80/questions/360962/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0